# NPM Erroring While Trying to Install Socket.IO

Tags: dns, installation, socket.io, npm

So I'm trying to install socket.io on my machine, and I'm coming across this little gem:

```
[ME ~]$ sudo npm install socket.io
npm ERR! Error: ENOTFOUND, Domain name not found
npm ERR!     at IOWatcher.callback (dns.js:74:15)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.35.13-92.fc14.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ME/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
[ME ~]$
```

I can't tell if it has to do with my firewall, my npm that I have installed, or some other such issue...has anyone encountered a similar issue?